# Best way to structure media query in sass

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, sass

What is the best way of structuring media query for mobile responsive approach.

Currently my idea is like this:

```
style-main.scss

_phone.scss
_tablet.scss
_desktop.scss
```

on each devices i have different breakpoints.
any idea ?

Comment: consider moving this question to Code Review

Comment: I'm not sure this would be on-topic for code review either.

Comment: It's not. Please consider reading our help center before making false suggestions. It's Code Review, not Directory Review.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the best way is to modularize the SCSS files by entity.
For example you can create a SCSS file for the footer, navbar, topbar, etc...
So you will have more readable files, better organized and easy to edit.
In your organization you could have long files hundreds and hundreds of lines and of course difficult to edit.

Answer (score -1):

The best approach to structure media query in sass is to use breakpoints libraries for sass [Breakpoints makes writing media queries in Sass super simple.](http://breakpoint-sass.com/),and also i recommend you to use singularity gs [Grids Without Limits](https://github.com/at-import/Singularity)